# Why I don't get the correct data from a view using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-view

Here is my view's data:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
DBEntities entities = new DBEntities();
var test = entities.V_UserPower.ToList();
```

[image]

What's strange is that `test` doesn't get the data as I expect. All four elements in list `test` are the same, and these values are not the same to view's sql result.

Why happened?

Comment: How have you defined the key of the EF model?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Database Context View Objects Not Working as Expected With MVC 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419411/database-context-view-objects-not-working-as-expected-with-mvc-4)

Answer (score 0):

possible duplicate of Database Context View Objects Not Working as Expected With MVC 4 –  Gert Arnold 2 days ago

Thanks Gert! That's where the problem is.